# Access div hidden parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating over a `div` using :

Can I access a hidden parameter in this `div` within the iteration ?

```
<DIV>
    <div id="myDiv" <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English"> />
</DIV>

$('#myDiv div.id').each(function() {
    //access a hidden parameter of the current div here
});
```

Comment: Yes you can. Can you show us HTML?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "hidden"? please, update properly your question giving further information.

Comment: And what do you exactly mean by "parameter"?

Comment: Do you mean attributes ?? how can attributes to be hidden !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following methods:

```
$('#myDiv div.id').each(
    function(){
        parameter = $(this).attr('data-hidden-parameter');
        /* or:
        parameter = $(this).data('hidden-parameter');
        */
    });
```

The first `parameter = $(this).attr('data-hidden-parameter')` requires the following structure:

```
<div class="id" data-hidden-parameter="value"><!-- other stuff --></div>
```

Whereas the latter works with getting/setting with the `data()` method of jQuery:

```
$(selector).data('hidden-parameter','value'); // sets
$(selector).data('hidden-parameter'); // gets
```

If you mean retrieving text, or other content/attributes, from a hidden element that's a child of the `div.id` element, with mark-up such as:

```
<div class="id">
    <input type="hidden" value="somethingOrOther" />
    <span style="display: none;">Some text in a hidden element</span>
</div>
```

You could retrieve that value with:

```
$('#myDiv div.id').each(
    function(){
        parameter = $(this).find('input:hidden').val();
        /* or:
        parameter = $(this).find('span').text();
    });
```

---

**Note** your jQuery selector implies you're iterating over a number of elements, based on the class of those elements, while your class-name, `id`, implies you're trying, instead, to search based on the `id` of an element. This might be pseudo-code to demonstrate your approach, but please don't use a class-name of `id`. It's perfectly valid, but it's terribly confusing. Albeit this is simply my own, personal, objection and response.

---

**Edited**, to supply a more targeted answer, by amending one of the above suggestions with an appropriate selector:

```
var parameter = $('#myDiv').find('input:hidden[name="Language"]').val();
```

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:hidden` selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

your `html` code is invalid: if you mean

```
 <div id="myDiv"><input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English"></div>
```

this will target your input

```
$('#myDiv input[type="hidden"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a tag inside another tag (or, in HTML or HTML-compatible XHTML, use self-closing tag syntax on a div). Your HTML is invalid and subject to whatever error recovery parsers care to put it though.

If you had, for instance:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <div class="id">
        <input type="hidden" name="Language" value="English">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could do:

```
$('#myDiv div.id').each(function(index, element) {
    var foo = $(element).find('input').val()
 });
```

… but you are probably better off using [data-*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) and jQuery's [`data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)